# Converting addon to EE3

Tags: add-on-development, ee3

Wonder is anyone can help me convert this EE2 addon to EE3

```
<?php

$plugin_info = array(
                        'pi_name'           => 'String',
                        'pi_version'        => '1.2.0',
                        'pi_author'         => 'Brett Altworth',
                        'pi_description'    => 'Allows string variables to be manipulated and printed in ways that are inconvenient with template tags alone.',
                        'pi_usage'          => String::usage()
                    );

class String {
    var $return_data = "";

    function String() {
        global $SESS, $TMPL;
        if(!isset($SESS->cache['string'])) {
            $SESS->cache['string'] = array();
        }

        if($TMPL->fetch_param('name') && isset($SESS->cache['string'][$TMPL->fetch_param('name')])) {
            $this->return_data = $SESS->cache['string'][$TMPL->fetch_param('name')];
        }
    }

    function set() {
        global $SESS;

        if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
            return;
        }

        $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
    }

    function clear() {
        global $SESS, $TMPL;

        if($TMPL->fetch_param('name') && isset($SESS->cache['string'][$TMPL->fetch_param('name')])) {
            unset($SESS->cache['string'][$TMPL->fetch_param('name')]);
        }
    }

    function append() {
        global $SESS;

        if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
            return;
        }

        if(!isset($SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']])) {
            $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
        } else {
            $str = "{$data['glue']}{$data['text']}";
            if($data['sep'] != "") {
                $str = "{$data['glue']}{$data['sep']}" . $str;
            }
            $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] . $str;
        }
    }

    function prepend() {
        global $SESS;

        if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
            return;
        }

        if(!isset($SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']])) {
            $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
        } else {
            $str = "{$data['text']}{$data['glue']}";
            if($data['sep'] != "") {
                $str .= "{$data['sep']}{$data['glue']}";
            }
            $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $str . $SESS->cache['string'][$data['name']];
        }
    }

    function output() {
        global $SESS, $TMPL, $FNS;

        $name = $TMPL->fetch_param('name');
        $value = "";

        if($name !== false && isset($SESS->cache['string'][$name])) {
            $value = trim($SESS->cache['string'][$name]);
        }

        if(trim($TMPL->tagdata) == "") {
            return $value;
        } else {
            $vars = $SESS->cache['string'];
            $vars['string'] = $value;
            $tagdata = $FNS->prep_conditionals($TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
            foreach($vars as $k=>$v) {
                $tagdata = $TMPL->swap_var_single($k, $v, $tagdata);
            }
            return $tagdata;
        }
    }

    function _get_params() {
        global $TMPL;

        $ret = array();
        $ret['text']    = false;
        $ret['name']    = $TMPL->fetch_param('name')        ? $TMPL->fetch_param('name') : false;
        $ret['sep']     = $TMPL->fetch_param('separator')   ? $TMPL->fetch_param('separator') : "";
        $ret['glue']    = $TMPL->fetch_param('glue')        ? $TMPL->fetch_param('glue') : "SPACE";

        if($TMPL->tagdata) {
            $ret['text'] = trim($TMPL->tagdata);
        } else if($TMPL->fetch_param('text')) {
            $ret['text'] = trim($TMPL->fetch_param('text'));
        } else if($TMPL->fetch_param('default')) {
            $ret['text'] = trim($TMPL->fetch_param('default'));
        }

        if(!$ret['name'] || !$ret['text']) {
            return false;
        }

        switch($ret['sep']) {
            case "SPACE"   : $ret['sep'] = " "; break;
            case "TAB"     : $ret['sep'] = "\t"; break;
            case "NEWLINE" : $ret['sep'] = "\n"; break;
            case "NONE"    : $ret['sep'] = ""; break;
        }

        switch($ret['glue']) {
            case "SPACE"   : $ret['glue'] = " "; break;
            case "TAB"     : $ret['glue'] = "\t"; break;
            case "NEWLINE" : $ret['glue'] = "\n"; break;
            case "NONE"    : $ret['glue'] = ""; break;
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    function usage() {
        ob_start();
        ?>See http://www.south.com/add-ons/string-plugin/ for documentation.<?php
        $buffer = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); 

        return $buffer;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting from EE2 to EE3 is easy. All the syntax's etc. are almost same. You just need to create an extra file named `addon.setup.php` and done.

In your case, follow the points below:

1. Open FTP and go to `your site/system/user/addons/`
2. Create a Folder named **string**. Enter in the folder.
3. Create a file named **pi.string.php** and put this code inside:

   ```
   $plugin_info = array(
           'pi_name'           => 'String',
           'pi_version'        => '1.2.0',
           'pi_author'         => 'Brett Altworth',
           'pi_description'    => 'Allows string variables to be manipulated and printed in ways that are inconvenient with template tags alone.',
           'pi_usage'          => string::usage()
       );

   class String {
       var $return_data = "";

       function __construct() {
           if(!isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'])) {
               $this->EE->session->cache['string'] = array();
           }

           /* Load EE Instance */
           $this->EE =& get_instance();

           if($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name') && isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name')])) {
               $this->return_data = $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name')];
           }
       }

       function set() {
           if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
               return;
           }

           $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
       }

       function clear() {
           if($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name') && isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name')])) {
               unset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name')]);
           }
       }

       function append() {
           if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
               return;
           }

           if(!isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']])) {
               $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
           } else {
               $str = "{$data['glue']}{$data['text']}";
               if($data['sep'] != "") {
                   $str = "{$data['glue']}{$data['sep']}" . $str;
               }
               $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] . $str;
           }
       }

       function prepend() {
           if(($data = $this->_get_params()) === false) {
               return;
           }

           if(!isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']])) {
               $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $data['text'];
           } else {
               $str = "{$data['text']}{$data['glue']}";
               if($data['sep'] != "") {
                   $str .= "{$data['sep']}{$data['glue']}";
               }
               $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']] = $str . $this->EE->session->cache['string'][$data['name']];
           }
       }

       function output() {
           global $FNS;

           $name = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name');
           $value = "";

           if($name !== false && isset($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$name])) {
               $value = trim($this->EE->session->cache['string'][$name]);
           }

           if(trim($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata) == "") {
               return $value;
           } else {
               $vars = $this->EE->session->cache['string'];
               $vars['string'] = $value;
               $tagdata = $FNS->prep_conditionals($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
               foreach($vars as $k=>$v) {
                   $tagdata = $this->EE->swap_var_single($k, $v, $tagdata);
               }
               return $tagdata;
           }
       }

       function _get_params() {
           global $TMPL;

           $ret = array();
           $ret['text']    = false;
           $ret['name']    = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name')        ? $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('name') : false;
           $ret['sep']     = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('separator')   ? $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('separator') : "";
           $ret['glue']    = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('glue')        ? $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('glue') : "SPACE";

           if($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata) {
               $ret['text'] = trim($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata);
           } else if($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('text')) {
               $ret['text'] = trim($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('text'));
           } else if($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('default')) {
               $ret['text'] = trim($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('default'));
           }

           if(!$ret['name'] || !$ret['text']) {
               return false;
           }

           switch($ret['sep']) {
               case "SPACE"   : $ret['sep'] = " "; break;
               case "TAB"     : $ret['sep'] = "\t"; break;
               case "NEWLINE" : $ret['sep'] = "\n"; break;
               case "NONE"    : $ret['sep'] = ""; break;
           }

           switch($ret['glue']) {
               case "SPACE"   : $ret['glue'] = " "; break;
               case "TAB"     : $ret['glue'] = "\t"; break;
               case "NEWLINE" : $ret['glue'] = "\n"; break;
               case "NONE"    : $ret['glue'] = ""; break;
           }

           return $ret;
       }

       static function usage() {
           ob_start();
           ?>See http://www.south.com/add-ons/string-plugin/ for documentation.<?php
           $buffer = ob_get_contents();
           ob_end_clean(); 

           return $buffer;
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Create a file named **addon.setup.php** and put this code inside:

   ```
   <?php
   return array(
       'author' => 'Brett Altworth',
       'author_url' => '#',
       'description' => 'Allows string variables to be manipulated and printed in ways that are inconvenient with template tags alone.',
       'docs_url' => '#',
       'name' => 'String',
       'settings_exist' => false,
       'version' => '1.2.0',
       'namespace'   => 'EllisLab\Addons\String',
   );
   ```
5. Install the plugin from backend.

Comment: Thanks Mufi, I tried your code but I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_param() on null in /home/H/xx/www/xx/user/addons/string/pi.string.php on line 21

Comment: Gotcha. I have edited answer. put the new code in your pi file

Comment: Hi Mufi, you are a champ. Thank you so much :D